# Method signature not resolving for kotlin in Java

Tags: spring, kotlin, graphql

IN my project I am using [graphql-spring-java](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot) to implement a graphql endpoint. I have the graphql schema defined and all the entities put together in kotlin. The problem is that one of my method signatures in my kotlin is not resolving correctly while all the other ones do. Here's the error verbatim:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.FieldResolverError: No method or field found with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment] as the last argument), in priority order:

  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.reservations()
  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.getReservations()
  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.reservations
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    ... 105 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.FieldResolverError: No method or field found with any of the following signatures (with or without one of [interface graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment] as the last argument), in priority order:

  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.reservations()
  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.getReservations()
  ninja.familyhomestay.domain.Host.reservations
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.FieldResolverScanner.missingFieldResolver(FieldResolverScanner.kt:51)
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.FieldResolverScanner.findFieldResolver(FieldResolverScanner.kt:42)
```

and here is the code in question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "host")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "host")
class Host(
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "host")
    var reservations: MutableSet<Reservation> = HashSet()
) : Serializable

@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Document(indexName = "reservation")
data class Reservation(
....
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "host_id")
    var host: Host? = null,
...) : Serializable {
    companion object {
        private const val serialVersionUID = 1L
    }
}
```

Obviously there's nothing wrong with code so I am thinking that it's an issue with kotlin. What do you think? I am using kotlin version `1.2.51` and `idea 2018.2.eap`.

Comment: Might decompiling the Kotlin bytecode back to Java help to find the solution?

Comment: I ended up reverting my host entity back to java:( and that fixed the issue. Just really strange that's the only class that I am having issues with.

Comment: Weird. So it shouldn't be a version issue either. Maybe you've got the time to debug the sources: https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-tools/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/coxautodev/graphql/tools/FieldResolverScanner.kt